# Creating adjacency matrix for undirected unweighted graph from spreadsheet

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have an csv file that looks like this:

```
Aitkin County, MN   27001   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Carlton County, MN  27017
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Crow Wing County, MN    27035
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Pine County, MN 27115
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
Anoka County, MN    27003   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Ramsey County, MN   27123
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Washington County, MN   27163
Becker County, MN   27005   Becker County, MN   27005
        Clay County, MN 27027
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Mahnomen County, MN 27087
        Norman County, MN   27107
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Wadena County, MN   27159
Beltrami County, MN 27007   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Koochiching County, MN  27071
        Lake of the Woods County, MN    27077
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Pennington County, MN   27113
        Roseau County, MN   27135
Benton County, MN   27009   Benton County, MN   27009
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Stearns County, MN  27145
Big Stone County, MN    27011   Big Stone County, MN    27011
        Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Swift County, MN    27151
        Traverse County, MN 27155
        Grant County, SD    46051
        Roberts County, SD  46109
Blue Earth County, MN   27013   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Brown County, MN    27015
        Faribault County, MN    27043
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Martin County, MN   27091
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Waseca County, MN   27161
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Brown County, MN    27015   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Brown County, MN    27015
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Carlton County, MN  27017   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Carlton County, MN  27017
        Pine County, MN 27115
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
        Douglas County, WI  55031
Carver County, MN   27019   Carver County, MN   27019
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Sibley County, MN   27143
        Wright County, MN   27171
Cass County, MN 27021   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Crow Wing County, MN    27035
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Todd County, MN 27153
        Wadena County, MN   27159
Chippewa County, MN 27023   Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Swift County, MN    27151
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
Chisago County, MN  27025   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Pine County, MN 27115
        Washington County, MN   27163
        Burnett County, WI  55013
        Polk County, WI 55095
Clay County, MN 27027   Becker County, MN   27005
        Clay County, MN 27027
        Norman County, MN   27107
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Wilkin County, MN   27167
        Cass County, ND 38017
        Richland County, ND 38077
Clearwater County, MN   27029   Becker County, MN   27005
        Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Mahnomen County, MN 27087
        Pennington County, MN   27113
        Polk County, MN 27119
Cook County, MN 27031   Keweenaw County, MI 26083
        Ontonagon County, MI    26131
        Cook County, MN 27031
        Lake County, MN 27075
        Ashland County, WI  55003
Cottonwood County, MN   27033   Brown County, MN    27015
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Jackson County, MN  27063
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Nobles County, MN   27105
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Crow Wing County, MN    27035   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Crow Wing County, MN    27035
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Morrison County, MN 27097
Dakota County, MN   27037   Dakota County, MN   27037
        Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Ramsey County, MN   27123
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Washington County, MN   27163
        Pierce County, WI   55093
Dodge County, MN    27039   Dodge County, MN    27039
        Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Steele County, MN   27147
Douglas County, MN  27041   Douglas County, MN  27041
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Todd County, MN 27153
Faribault County, MN    27043   Kossuth County, IA  19109
        Winnebago County, IA    19189
        Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Faribault County, MN    27043
        Freeborn County, MN 27047
        Martin County, MN   27091
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Fillmore County, MN 27045   Howard County, IA   19089
        Winneshiek County, IA   19191
        Fillmore County, MN 27045
        Houston County, MN  27055
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Winona County, MN   27169
Freeborn County, MN 27047   Winnebago County, IA    19189
        Worth County, IA    19195
        Faribault County, MN    27043
        Freeborn County, MN 27047
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Steele County, MN   27147
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Goodhue County, MN  27049   Dakota County, MN   27037
        Dodge County, MN    27039
        Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Wabasha County, MN  27157
        Pepin County, WI    55091
        Pierce County, WI   55093
Grant County, MN    27051   Douglas County, MN  27041
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Traverse County, MN 27155
        Wilkin County, MN   27167
Hennepin County, MN 27053   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Carver County, MN   27019
        Dakota County, MN   27037
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Ramsey County, MN   27123
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Wright County, MN   27171
Houston County, MN  27055   Allamakee County, IA    19005
        Winneshiek County, IA   19191
        Fillmore County, MN 27045
        Houston County, MN  27055
        Winona County, MN   27169
        La Crosse County, WI    55063
        Vernon County, WI   55123
Hubbard County, MN  27057   Becker County, MN   27005
        Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Wadena County, MN   27159
Isanti County, MN   27059   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Pine County, MN 27115
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
Itasca County, MN   27061   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Koochiching County, MN  27071
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
Jackson County, MN  27063   Dickinson County, IA    19059
        Emmet County, IA    19063
        Osceola County, IA  19143
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Jackson County, MN  27063
        Martin County, MN   27091
        Nobles County, MN   27105
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Kanabec County, MN  27065   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Pine County, MN 27115
Kandiyohi County, MN    27067   Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Swift County, MN    27151
Kittson County, MN  27069   Kittson County, MN  27069
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Roseau County, MN   27135
        Pembina County, ND  38067
Koochiching County, MN  27071   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Koochiching County, MN  27071
        Lake of the Woods County, MN    27077
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073   Big Stone County, MN    27011
        Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073
        Swift County, MN    27151
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
        Deuel County, SD    46039
        Grant County, SD    46051
Lake County, MN 27075   Cook County, MN 27031
        Lake County, MN 27075
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
        Ashland County, WI  55003
        Bayfield County, WI 55007
        Douglas County, WI  55031
Lake of the Woods County, MN    27077   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Koochiching County, MN  27071
        Lake of the Woods County, MN    27077
        Roseau County, MN   27135
Le Sueur County, MN 27079   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Sibley County, MN   27143
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Lincoln County, MN  27081   Lincoln County, MN  27081
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Pipestone County, MN    27117
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
        Brookings County, SD    46011
        Deuel County, SD    46039
        Moody County, SD    46101
Lyon County, MN 27083   Lincoln County, MN  27081
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Pipestone County, MN    27117
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
McLeod County, MN   27085   Carver County, MN   27019
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Sibley County, MN   27143
        Wright County, MN   27171
Mahnomen County, MN 27087   Becker County, MN   27005
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Mahnomen County, MN 27087
        Norman County, MN   27107
        Polk County, MN 27119
Marshall County, MN 27089   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Kittson County, MN  27069
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Pennington County, MN   27113
        Polk County, MN 27119
        Roseau County, MN   27135
        Grand Forks County, ND  38035
        Pembina County, ND  38067
        Walsh County, ND    38099
Martin County, MN   27091   Emmet County, IA    19063
        Kossuth County, IA  19109
        Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Faribault County, MN    27043
        Jackson County, MN  27063
        Martin County, MN   27091
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Meeker County, MN   27093   Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Wright County, MN   27171
Mille Lacs County, MN   27095   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Benton County, MN   27009
        Crow Wing County, MN    27035
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
Morrison County, MN 27097   Benton County, MN   27009
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Crow Wing County, MN    27035
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Todd County, MN 27153
Mower County, MN    27099   Howard County, IA   19089
        Mitchell County, IA 19131
        Worth County, IA    19195
        Dodge County, MN    27039
        Fillmore County, MN 27045
        Freeborn County, MN 27047
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Steele County, MN   27147
Murray County, MN   27101   Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Nobles County, MN   27105
        Pipestone County, MN    27117
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Rock County, MN 27133
Nicollet County, MN 27103   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Brown County, MN    27015
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Sibley County, MN   27143
Nobles County, MN   27105   Lyon County, IA 19119
        Osceola County, IA  19143
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Jackson County, MN  27063
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Nobles County, MN   27105
        Rock County, MN 27133
Norman County, MN   27107   Becker County, MN   27005
        Clay County, MN 27027
        Mahnomen County, MN 27087
        Norman County, MN   27107
        Polk County, MN 27119
        Cass County, ND 38017
        Traill County, ND   38097
Olmsted County, MN  27109   Dodge County, MN    27039
        Fillmore County, MN 27045
        Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Wabasha County, MN  27157
        Winona County, MN   27169
Todd County, MN 27111   Becker County, MN   27005
        Clay County, MN 27027
        Douglas County, MN  27041
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Todd County, MN 27153
        Wadena County, MN   27159
        Wilkin County, MN   27167
Pennington County, MN   27113   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Pennington County, MN   27113
        Polk County, MN 27119
        Red Lake County, MN 27125
Pine County, MN 27115   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Carlton County, MN  27017
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Kanabec County, MN  27065
        Pine County, MN 27115
        Burnett County, WI  55013
        Douglas County, WI  55031
Pipestone County, MN    27117   Lincoln County, MN  27081
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Pipestone County, MN    27117
        Rock County, MN 27133
        Brookings County, SD    46011
        Minnehaha County, SD    46099
        Moody County, SD    46101
Polk County, MN 27119   Clearwater County, MN   27029
        Mahnomen County, MN 27087
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Norman County, MN   27107
        Pennington County, MN   27113
        Polk County, MN 27119
        Red Lake County, MN 27125
        Grand Forks County, ND  38035
        Traill County, ND   38097
Pope County, MN 27121   Douglas County, MN  27041
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Swift County, MN    27151
Ramsey County, MN   27123   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Dakota County, MN   27037
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Ramsey County, MN   27123
        Washington County, MN   27163
Red Lake County, MN 27125   Pennington County, MN   27113
        Polk County, MN 27119
        Red Lake County, MN 27125
Redwood County, MN  27127   Brown County, MN    27015
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
Renville County, MN 27129   Brown County, MN    27015
        Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Sibley County, MN   27143
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
Rice County, MN 27131   Dakota County, MN   27037
        Dodge County, MN    27039
        Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Steele County, MN   27147
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Rock County, MN 27133   Lyon County, IA 19119
        Murray County, MN   27101
        Nobles County, MN   27105
        Pipestone County, MN    27117
        Rock County, MN 27133
        Minnehaha County, SD    46099
        Moody County, SD    46101
Roseau County, MN   27135   Beltrami County, MN 27007
        Kittson County, MN  27069
        Lake of the Woods County, MN    27077
        Marshall County, MN 27089
        Roseau County, MN   27135
St. Louis County, MN    27137   Aitkin County, MN   27001
        Carlton County, MN  27017
        Itasca County, MN   27061
        Koochiching County, MN  27071
        Lake County, MN 27075
        St. Louis County, MN    27137
        Douglas County, WI  55031
Scott County, MN    27139   Carver County, MN   27019
        Dakota County, MN   27037
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Sibley County, MN   27143
Sherburne County, MN    27141   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Benton County, MN   27009
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        Isanti County, MN   27059
        Mille Lacs County, MN   27095
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Wright County, MN   27171
Sibley County, MN   27143   Carver County, MN   27019
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Nicollet County, MN 27103
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Scott County, MN    27139
        Sibley County, MN   27143
Stearns County, MN  27145   Benton County, MN   27009
        Douglas County, MN  27041
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Todd County, MN 27153
        Wright County, MN   27171
Steele County, MN   27147   Dodge County, MN    27039
        Freeborn County, MN 27047
        Mower County, MN    27099
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Steele County, MN   27147
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Stevens County, MN  27149   Big Stone County, MN    27011
        Douglas County, MN  27041
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Swift County, MN    27151
        Traverse County, MN 27155
Swift County, MN    27151   Big Stone County, MN    27011
        Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Kandiyohi County, MN    27067
        Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073
        Pope County, MN 27121
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Swift County, MN    27151
Todd County, MN 27153   Cass County, MN 27021
        Douglas County, MN  27041
        Morrison County, MN 27097
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Todd County, MN 27153
        Wadena County, MN   27159
Traverse County, MN 27155   Big Stone County, MN    27011
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Stevens County, MN  27149
        Traverse County, MN 27155
        Wilkin County, MN   27167
        Richland County, ND 38077
        Roberts County, SD  46109
Wabasha County, MN  27157   Goodhue County, MN  27049
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Wabasha County, MN  27157
        Winona County, MN   27169
        Buffalo County, WI  55011
        Pepin County, WI    55091
Wadena County, MN   27159   Becker County, MN   27005
        Cass County, MN 27021
        Hubbard County, MN  27057
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Todd County, MN 27153
        Wadena County, MN   27159
Waseca County, MN   27161   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Faribault County, MN    27043
        Freeborn County, MN 27047
        Le Sueur County, MN 27079
        Rice County, MN 27131
        Steele County, MN   27147
        Waseca County, MN   27161
Washington County, MN   27163   Anoka County, MN    27003
        Chisago County, MN  27025
        Dakota County, MN   27037
        Ramsey County, MN   27123
        Washington County, MN   27163
        Pierce County, WI   55093
        Polk County, WI 55095
        St. Croix County, WI    55109
    27165   Blue Earth County, MN   27013
        Brown County, MN    27015
        Cottonwood County, MN   27033
        Jackson County, MN  27063
        Martin County, MN   27091
        Watonwan County, MN 27165
Wilkin County, MN   27167   Clay County, MN 27027
        Grant County, MN    27051
        Otter Tail County, MN   27111
        Traverse County, MN 27155
        Wilkin County, MN   27167
        Richland County, ND 38077
Winona County, MN   27169   Fillmore County, MN 27045
        Houston County, MN  27055
        Olmsted County, MN  27109
        Wabasha County, MN  27157
        Winona County, MN   27169
        Buffalo County, WI  55011
        La Crosse County, WI    55063
        Trempealeau County, WI  55121
Wright County, MN   27171   Carver County, MN   27019
        Hennepin County, MN 27053
        McLeod County, MN   27085
        Meeker County, MN   27093
        Sherburne County, MN    27141
        Stearns County, MN  27145
        Wright County, MN   27171
Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173   Chippewa County, MN 27023
        Lac qui Parle County, MN    27073
        Lincoln County, MN  27081
        Lyon County, MN 27083
        Redwood County, MN  27127
        Renville County, MN 27129
        Yellow Medicine County, MN  27173
        Deuel County, SD    46039
```

I need to create an adjacency matrix for an undirected unweighted graph representing the neighbor relationship.

So the leftmost column would represent a node. The 3rd column would represent the neighbors of the node in the leftmost column. The table above is just a snippet of the whole data.

Also, I am not trying to parse XML, HTML code. I just wanted to add a snippet of the data in tabular format but I am not sure why it's still displaying the HTML.

Could you all please suggest how to do the same?
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: Search hint: `[python] parse xml`. If you aren't familiar with searching here on SO, `[python]` means "search in questions tagged `python`", and `parse xml` is what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am not trying to parse XML, HTML code. I just wanted to add a snippet of the data in tabular format but I am not sure why it's still displaying the HTML.

Comment: @itprorh66
Any approach is fine with me. I just need to build the adjacency matrix. After that I have other things to do with the graph.

Comment: If your input is a .csv file, then delete the snippet from your question, and post the .csv file as a code block.

Comment: @user3386109
Could you please help me out with how to add the .csv file? Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ziRLoo22AbORwqbgg-LS-IkpmNb0rQez/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Copy the text. Paste the text into your question. Select the text that you've just pasted. Press the code button, which looks like this `{}`

Answer (score 1):

I created a dictionary with the leftmost column as the keys and the third column as the values. Then just create the adjacency matrix with the keys as nodes and values of the dictionary as neighbors.

```
minnesota_county_filtered = pd.read_excel('../data/MN_Counties.xlsx',     usecols=['source', 'neighbor'])
minnesota_county_filtered["source"] = minnesota_county_filtered["source"].str.replace(" County, MN", "")
minnesota_county_filtered["neighbor"] = minnesota_county_filtered["neighbor"].str.replace(" County, MN", "")
result = minnesota_county_filtered.groupby('source')['neighbor'].apply(list).to_dict()
result = {k: [v.strip() for v in vs] for k, vs in result.items()}
edges = [(a, b) for a, bs in result.items() for b in bs]
df = pd.DataFrame(edges)
adj_matrix = pd.crosstab(df[0], df[1])
```

Result:
[image]